# Report to display users and their respective roles assigned to then, also display the number of roles assigned to a particular users

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    pu.username, prdt.role_name, prdt.description, 
    prd.role_common_name, COUNT(*) cnt   --> this
FROM 
    per_users pu 
JOIN
    per_user_roles pur ON pur.user_id = pu.user_id 
JOIN
    per_roles_dn prd ON prd.role_id = pur.role_id 
JOIN
    per_roles_dn_tl prdt ON prdt.role_id = prd.role_id
GROUP BY 
    pu.username, --> and this prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name
```

Can anyone help me retrieve the one more column of the number of roles assigned to a particular users column?

Comment: Edit you question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display `pu.username, prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name` along with the role count per user then you don't need a group by clause rather count()over() window function will do the trick.

```
SELECT pu.username, prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name, count(prdt.role_name)over(partition by pu.username) role_count_per_user
FROM per_users pu JOIN
     per_user_roles pur
     ON pur.user_id = pu.user_id JOIN
     per_roles_dn prd
     ON prd.role_id = pur.role_id JOIN
     per_roles_dn_tl prdt
    ON prdt.role_id = prd.role_id
```

But if there are possibilities to have same role assigned to an user multiple times (unlikely) and you need that count then group by is the right approach.

```
SELECT pu.username, prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name, COUNT(*)cnt
FROM per_users pu JOIN
     per_user_roles pur
     ON pur.user_id = pu.user_id JOIN
     per_roles_dn prd
     ON prd.role_id = pur.role_id JOIN
     per_roles_dn_tl prdt
    ON prdt.role_id = prd.role_id
GROUP BY pu.username, and this prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name
```